# How to form possessive from "belongs to X (preposition) Y"

Tags: grammaticality

This is none's of us business.

Everyone's in the room pockets were empty.

The car isn't anyone's from this town.

Are the sentences correct? If not, how should they be phrased correctly?

Comment: The possessive suffix goes on the word at the end of the noun phrase, not on the head noun (unless it's the last word in the phrase). So all three sentences are ungrammatical. The possessive form of _us_ is _our_, so _none of our business_ is the usual way to say (1). And _Everone in the room's pockets were empty_ is grammatical, though awkward. But (3) would probly use the verb _belong to_. The suffixal clitic possessive competes with the _of_ possessive, and this is one of the reasons -- the more complex the construction, the more syntax it needs, and the less morphology.

Comment: The possessive apostrophe comes *after* the noun (or *noun phrase*), but because it's an awkward construction we'd normally avoid *a long noun phrase's* and use *of a long noun phrase*. Also, we rarely use *of us* - it's ***our***.

Comment: Only your second example actually refers to the noun phrase mentioned in your question.  I would answer, but I don't want to muck up the answer with regard to addressing the examples that aren't in line with your question.  In general, a noun phrase is a single unit and takes all of the ownership: "captain of the police of Calgary's decision".  Awkward, but correct.

Comment: Thank you. Still little question about the first sentence (as I explained in a comment below). Cord: Where did I mention nouns in the title? The other two sentences follow the structure with a word (indefinite pronoun) being followed by a preposition (of and from, respectively) and then another word/pronoun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct versions are:

- **This is none of our business**. You always form a posessive from a pronoun by modifying the pronoun: 'the business of us' is 'our business'
- If you insist on structuring the sentence like that it is "**Everyone in the room's pockets were empty**". The noun phrase is "everyone in the room" and you can technically make it possessive like that. But it's clumsy.
- Likewise "**The car isn't anyone from this town's**" is technically correct, but would be better phrased differently.

Comment: Thank you. I just have little inquiry about the first one. I sometimes see "none of X's business" used to refer to single person just for emphasis, in my sentence I want to put emphasis on that our group does not contain a single person to whom it belongs, rather than on the fact it does not belong to the group as a whole. I presume it is impossible to make the difference between these two without replacing the 's with of or belong to?